# Audio doesn't work in HDMI in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, lubuntu, radeon, hdmi

I already created an asoundrc file. This is what the file looks like:
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
} 
and audio still does not go through HDMI to my HDTV. I am sure that the TV doesn't have a problem but I think the card is the problem. My Card is ATI Radeon HD 3450 by dell. I also installed the Non-free driver for linux and whenever I go to alsa, it says that there is 2 sound cards. It says HDA Intel and HDA ATI HDMI. Thanks in advance. =) (This is not muted)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Lnq.jpg

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and expand on what you mean by "the .asoundrc thing" and tell us Have you checked `alsamixer` to insure the desired sound card isn't muted?

Comment: As it is, we still don't have enough information to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `aplay -l` and also open a terminal and issue the command `alsamixer`, then press F6 to display the card menu, take a screenshot with CTRL-ALT-PrtSc and upload it to imgur.com and provide a link. This will help us help you! I thank you and the community thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following command to install the pulse audio volume control

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

do a search for the app or execute pavucontrol. This is not the same as the volume control on your panel.

You will have more control over card selection and assigning devices. Also, sometimes unplugging and plugging the HDMI back in automatically toggles it into a working state.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This fixed my problem that I have been trying to fix ever since I got this card. =D